# Postman request not sending "+", "#" keywords to Web api

Tags: search, special-characters

I have created a web api with search option. For checking the api, i have used Postman tool in that i have provided symbols like "+", "#" for search. It is not recognized by the Web api Get method parameter.

From Postman Get Method() ->

```
http://localhost:60670/api/home?query=#
```

"query" is the parameter for search, in that i have given "+" or "#" keyword.

`public IActionResult Get(string query)`

But from the code it is not recognized by the Get method and "query" parameter is showing "null".

Help on this please!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

few ways to do it:

1- encode your parameters :   `+` --> `%2B` and `#` --> `%23` (and any other special character)  SEE : http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

2- send via `POST` instead of `GET` (I prefer this)

Comment: The provided document does not seem helpful. I'm not able to find the required codes

Answer (score 1):

Encode your parameters:

```
original path = \Documents\FDS_D7U_C180175P+001005.pdf
encode path   =  %5C%20Documents%5CFDS_D7U_C180175P%2B001005.pdf
```

1. Enter the encoded path on the postman.
2. click on send.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWvRE.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ad0XB.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahnxs.png]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557